# typeorm how to leftjoin with count without relation

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I have `user` entity and `follow` entity as following currently.

```
export class Follow extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    @Column()
    userId: number;

    @Column()
    followingId: number;
}

export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  username!: string;
}
```

The current code to retrieve user, which works fine.

```
      const u = await getRepository(User).createQueryBuilder("user").where("user.id = :id", { id: id})
        .leftJoinAndMapMany("user.following", Follow, "following", "user.id = following.userId")
        .leftJoinAndMapMany("user.follower", Follow, "follower", "user.id = follower.followingId")
        .getOne();

        u.followingCount = u.following.length;
        u.followerCount = u.follower.length;
```

it will produce the following result as example:

```
User {
  id: 1,
  username: "sample",
  follower: [
    Follow {
     id: 5,
     userId: 1,
     followingId: 3,
    }
  ],
  following: [
    Follow {
     id: 4,
     userId: 3,
     followingId: 1,
    }
  ],
  followingCount: 1,
  followerCount: 1
}
```

I wonder there are any ways I can use `typeORM` in-build function, upon the above code, to put all 4 following properties under a `follow` field, and also do the `COUNT` at the same time. So it would look like the following:

```
User {
  id: 1,
  username: "sample",
  follow: {
    follower: [],
    following: [],
    followingCount,
    followerCount
  }
}
```

**Note:** I know I can use `@ManyToMany` for two entities, and my example appears to be the case.
but there are many cases that two table has no relationship but we still want to join them together.
I try to bring the idea into a more general situation so it can be used regardless the relation is built. And also better understand the `typeORM` in-build functions.

Any suggestions are appreciated.